# RoR: Access local storage element in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to transfer some local storage values to another page but before that I need to do some calculation in Rails controller on those local storage items.
How could I pass the local storage items via a button click which transfers the data to the controller method.

Answer (score 1):

The local storage is a client-only concept. In contrast to cookies, local storage values stay on the client and are not send with each request to the server.

Therefore you have to transfer the values manually via JavaScript and XHR to the server.

Example (with jquery):

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/save_local_storage',
    data: localStorage
});
```

(However you want probably send some user id with it.)

Additionally a site with domain A can't set local storage values for site with domain B. So you have to transfer those values on the serverside (via the database, memcache, redis, ...)

Comment: How it would be ?